# Python-Pandas: Continue row value increment with adding a different database

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

So I have a df that goes like this df1:

| 10AE | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1427 | New York |
| 1428 | Los Angeles |
| 1429 | Karachi |
| 1430 | London |
| 1431 | Barcelona |
| 1432 | Madrid |

Now i have another database that has a similar columns but different citys df2:

| 10AE | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New Orleans |
| 2 | San Francisco |
| 3 | Manchester |
| 4 | Toronto |
| 5 | Atlanta |
| 6 | Lahore |

I want to append the second database into the first one but continue the incrementing row values from the first one like this:

| 10AE | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1427 | New York |
| 1428 | Los Angeles |
| 1429 | Karachi |
| 1430 | London |
| 1431 | Barcelona |
| 1432 | Madrid |
| 1433 | New Orleans |
| 1434 | San Francisco |
| 1435 | Manchester |
| 1436 | Toronto |
| 1437 | Atlanta |
| 1438 | Lahore |

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Any help would be appreciated!!

Thank you so much!!

Comment: [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) has `ignore_index=True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
last_row = int(df1['10AE'].tail(1))+1
df2['10AE'] = range(last_row, last_row+len(df2))
```

and then you can concatenate `df2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple hack you can do

```
df2['10AE'] = 1
df2.iloc[0,0] = df1.iloc[-1,0] + 1
df2['10AE'] = df2['10AE'].cumsum()
```

After that you can concat the dfs

but there's probably more efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the max of df1's `10AE` column to df2's `10AE` column. Then concat them together.

```
df2['10AE'] += 1432

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
print(df)

# Output:

    10AE           City
0   1427       New York
1   1428    Los Angeles
2   1429        Karachi
3   1430         London
4   1431      Barcelona
5   1432         Madrid
6   1433    New Orleans
7   1434  San Francisco
8   1435     Manchester
9   1436        Toronto
10  1437        Atlanta
11  1438          Lahor
```